# How can I programmatically force sort on slickGrid with dataView?

Tags: sorting, slickgrid

I have a slickGrid which is using dataView to render student grades. I would like to default sort the grid prior to it being rendered by column with id = 0 and field = 'Student'. How can I trigger sort event on this column before the grid renders?

The reason why I want to do this is because I have a really strange bug that can be seen in this video:

http://screencast.com/t/Oz0vlcsQPp

The sorter works fine on the 1st asc/des sort but then it goes all out of whack. Noting is sorted the way it should be. However if I 1st sort by student name then the sorter on any other column works just fine without any issues no matter how many times I sort. If I refresh the page the problem happens again.

Since I cannot even begin to understand why is this happening my only hope is to initially fire a sort on the student column and bypass the problem all together.

NOTE: I am using the naturalSort.js from here: https://github.com/overset/javascript-natural-sort/blob/master/naturalSort.js. I don't think the sort is the issue since it works fine when I initially sort by student name... This one is breaking my brain...

EDIT: As you can see in the video my grid cell data looks something like "A (78.65%)". My data structure looks like this:

```
"Column_3":{"displayValue":"A (100%)","sortValue":100.0},
"Column_4":{"displayValue":"B (87.53%)","sortValue":87.53},
"Column_5":{"displayValue":"?","sortValue":-1.0}
```

I am sending over an object for sorting reasons in order to use percentage as a sorting criteria. In order to make this work I have defined dataItemColumnValueExtractor in grid options as such:

```
self.options["dataItemColumnValueExtractor"] = getItemColumnValue;
function getItemColumnValue(item, column) {
    var values = item[column.field];
    return values.displayValue !== undefined ? values.displayValue : values;
}
```

This allows me to use the sortValue data to sort the grid. Here is my sort event:

```
    grid.onSort.subscribe(function(e, args){
        var comparer = function(a, b) {
            var result;
            if (a[args.sortCol.field].sortValue !== undefined && a[args.sortCol.field].sortValue !== null && b[args.sortCol.field].sortValue !== undefined && b[args.sortCol.field].sortValue !== null) {
                result = naturalSort(a[args.sortCol.field].sortValue,b[args.sortCol.field].sortValue);
            }
            else {
                result = naturalSort(a[args.sortCol.field],b[args.sortCol.field]);
            }
            return result;
        };
        dataView.sort(comparer, args.sortAsc);
    });
```

Bottom line is everything works fine except the above mentioned issue with sorting... Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all...your issue for first time sorting is something else which can be fixed...

But if you want to sort a col on grid load you can trigger the click event....

```
$(function () {
for (var i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
var d = (data[i] = {});

d["num"] = i;
.
.
d["effortDriven"] = (i % 5 == 0);
} 

dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView();
grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", dataView, columns, options);

$('.slick-header-columns').children().eq(2).trigger('click');  // eq(2) for the 3rd col
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain how can I fix the actual sort problem? You make it sound like you've dealt with this type of issue in the past. The problem for me is that I can't see a pattern. If I sort by student name column then all sorting works fine which leads me to believe that the problem is not the sort function itself but something in the settings of the grid. If you want I can provide you with my code...

Comment: I have added some additional info with regards to how my code works with some example data and relevant grid code. I would appreciate if you could point me in the right direction...

Comment: I have never faced this issue...but I think you are missing somewhere updating or rendering the grid

Comment: You might be having some NaN value in some numerical column of the grid....probably

Comment: Your solution worked. I know it's a hack but I really don't have time to figure out what is the cause of this since it's such an edge case. You know how it is there are always more pressing issues. Thx for your help!